# mTLS and rpc client verification in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Question related to client to server encryption on https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/secure/tls-encryption/client-to-server/

Is this mTLS? Is the rpc server verifying the rpc client? And does it cover ysql or ycql clients ?
When using something like yb-admin over tls, does the server verify a certificate presented by the yb-admin like tool?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding client <-> server connections, for YSQL it’s mTLS. Mutual TLS (mTLS) is a type of authentication in which the two parties in a connection authenticate each other using the TLS protocol. See https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/secure/tls-encryption/client-to-server/ for more.

For server <-> server, it’s mTLS for both YCQL & YSQL (the server uses an internal layer for server to server communication). See https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/secure/tls-encryption/server-to-server/ for more information.